# pgloader quote handling problems when create table for default values

Tags: postgresql, mariadb, pgloader

I'm trying migrate my DB from maria DB to PGSQL.

I have a script file

```
LOAD DATABASE
FROM mysql://user:pass@server/mysql-db
INTO postgresql://user:pass@server:port/pg-db;
```

After running I'm getting some log and error:

```
2019-02-10T12:50:58.837000Z INFO CREATE TABLE ao_e8b6cc_git_hub_event
(
  created_at             timestamptz not null,
  git_hub_id             text not null default ''0'',
  id                     bigserial not null,
  repository_id          bigint not null,
  save_point             boolean default NULL
);
```

In mysql DB I have a table `ao_e8b6cc_git_hub_event`

This table contains column `git_hub_id` STRING with default value 0

I think problem in `text not null default ''0''`

pgloader makes two single quotes. How I can fix it?

Comment: Try double quotes:  `"` instead of two single-quotes (aka 'apostrophes').

Comment: What do you mean? This is scripts generates automatically and push it to PGSQL
I don't know how replace '' to " before running.